# The code won't change when saving (ctrl + s) .astro file

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

So im new to astro, and i tried to change the code on my Navbar.astro components but there is some "bug" happened when i save (ctrl + s) the code didn't want to change

Before Change:
[image: Before Change]

After Change:
[image: After Change]

After Saving the `.astro` file (ctrl + s):
[image]

it became `<nav>` element? i don't know what happened

Comment: Maybe there is an invisible character in the second </nav> closing tag, because you copied it from somewhere else, and because of that your editor wanted to fix the error, by adding a closing tag. But I am not sure tbh. What editor are you using?
Another reason could be some syncing or backuping tool you are using.

Comment: Make sure it's not due to any save actions or formatters e.g. Prettier or anything like that - disable them and try it again.

Comment: Hello @Alex thank you for the advice, i've been disabled the "editor.defaultFormatter": "astro-build.astro-vscode" in my user setting in VSCode, and it is solved :)